# Candidate key or Super key

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Consider a relational table with different columns, what would you call the collection of unique and not null values, super key or candidate key?

Comment: Well, what are the definitions of the terms? What did googling your question give?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Superkey, candidate key & primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337309/superkey-candidate-key-primary-key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an empty SQL table have a superkey? Does every SQL table have one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024902/does-an-empty-sql-table-have-a-superkey-does-every-sql-table-have-one)

Answer (score 1):

A **Super key** is a set or one of more columns to uniquely identify rows in a table.

**Candidate keys** are selected from the set of super keys, the only thing we take care while selecting candidate key is: It should not have any redundant attribute. That’s the reason they are also termed as minimal super key.

In `Employee` table there are Three Columns : `Emp_Code,Emp_Number,Emp_Name`

**Super keys:**

All of the following sets are able to uniquely identify rows of the employee table.

```
{Emp_Code}
{Emp_Number}
{Emp_Code, Emp_Number}
{Emp_Code, Emp_Name}
{Emp_Code, Emp_Number, Emp_Name}
{Emp_Number, Emp_Name}
```

**Candidate Keys:**

As I stated above, they are the minimal super keys with no redundant attributes.

```
{Emp_Code}
{Emp_Number}
```

As a **Summary**:

A **Superkey** is a set of columns that uniquely identifies a row.Whereas a **Candidate** key would be a MINIMAL set of columns that uniquely identifies a row. So essentially a **Superkey** is a **Candidate key** with extra unnecessary columns in it.

Comment: A CK is a superkey. So a superkey does not necessarily have more coluns thana a CK.